# continued fraction for a ratio of modified Bessel functions

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a continued fraction for ratio* $K_2/K_1$, $K_n$ being the $2$nd-kind modified **Bessel** fct of order $n$.

- my original equivalent problem regarding ratio $${dK1(x)\over dx}/K1(x)$$ for a real $x$

Comment: There is an intrinsic issue since neither $K_1(x),K_2(x)$ or $\frac{K_2(x)}{K_1(x)}$ are bounded in a right neighbourhood of zero.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a way to express this ratio in terms of a continued fraction. The idea can be found in a paper by N.M. Temme. You can also find this information on page 239 of this link:
http://apps.nrbook.com/fortran/index.html
(see Eqs. 6.7.24 to 6.7.27)

Comment: Thank you Javier, but your link has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: Did you read Eq. 6.7.24? This equations gives a continued fraction for the ratio of K-Bessel functions. Therefore, it does have to do with the problem at hand. But if you don't want to believe it, it's OK.

Comment: Updated link: http://numerical.recipes/book/book.html

Comment: Thanks, on the updated link, this is  Eqs (6.6.24) to (6.6.27)